# Why does setResult not direct back to previous Activity in onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android

I'm sending a `startActivityForResult` from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB`

```
private Uri saveFileToDrive() {
    Intent saveToDriveInten = new Intent(this, GoogleDriveProxeyActivity.class);
    saveToDriveInten.putExtra("fileUri", mCurrentImageUri.toString());
    startActivityForResult(saveToDriveInten, SAVE_TO_DRIVE);
    return null;
}
```

and in `ActivityB` I see:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("driveUri", file.getAlternateLink());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

How come I'm not back to `onActivityResult` of `ActivityA`?

Actually I'm not sure what code is executed after

`setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);`

I thought i was missing `finish()` but this threw me to another parent Activity.

Comment: Instead of posting a question on here and saying ``am i missing finish()`` why not try it first and if that doesn't work post a question

Comment: I thought i was missing `finish()` but this threw me to other parent Activity

Comment: That's what finish() does. It finishes your current activity, you will be returned to whatever activity called the second activity. As the answers have stated below, the setResult() doesn't do anything until you call finish. It just sets what the reuslt will be when the activity finishes, which is passed to the onActivityResult. As soon as finish is called, the onActivityResult function will be called.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to call `finish()` after `setResult()`.

Calling `setResult()` does not close or otherwise end the current Activity, so it will still be visible to the user. `onActivityResult()` is not called until the other Activity is finished.

Comment: I thought i was missing `finish()` but this threw me to other parent Activity.

Answer (score 3):

> am I missing finish()

Yes. Call `finish()` after `setResult()`

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra("driveUri", file.getAlternateLink());
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
```

[According to the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int, android.content.Intent))

> Call this to set the result that your activity will return to its caller.

Notice the word "set". You still need to return control to the receiving `Activity`.

Comment: do I call empty ctor `new Intent();` ? or do I need to fill it's origin and destination?

Comment: Empty constructor. It looks like you are doing it correctly just not giving control back to the previous `Activity`.

Comment: I thought i was missing `finish()` but this threw me to other parent Activity.

Comment: Are you saying it goes to the `Activity` before `ActivityA`? If so, do you call `finish()` in `ActivityA` somewhere, have `noHistory=true` in your `manifest.xml`, or have do not keep activities set on your device?